# No reults shown in logcat by PlaceDetectionBuffer

Tags: android, google-places-api

Below is my code for getting likely places around my current location , I i have checked that api is enabled and mGoogleApiclient is connected also , but no places are being printed in logcat

```
public class PlacesAPIActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
private static final String LOG_TAG = "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP";
private static final int GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID = 0;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 100;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_places_api);
    Log.d("resuktfvvvfdfd", "onCreate: ");
    Button currentButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.currentButton);
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(PlacesAPIActivity.this)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .enableAutoManage(this, GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID, this)
            .build();
    Log.d("connected", String.valueOf(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()));
    currentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                Log.d("connected1", String.valueOf(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()));
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(PlacesAPIActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(PlacesAPIActivity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                            PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                } else {
                    callPlaceDetectionApi();
                }

            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Google Places API connection failed with error code: "
            + connectionResult.getErrorCode());

    Toast.makeText(this,
            "Google Places API connection failed with error code:" +
                    connectionResult.getErrorCode(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                callPlaceDetectionApi();
            }
            break;
    }
}

private void callPlaceDetectionApi() throws SecurityException {
    Log.d("mvkvkmvkmvkm", "callPlaceDetectionApi: ");
    PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
            .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
    Log.d("result",result.toString());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
            for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, String.format("Place '%s' with " +
                                "likelihood: %g",
                        placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
                        placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));
            }
            likelyPlaces.release();
        }
    });
}
```

And my logcat Looks like

```
    06-26 16:17:10.842 8874-8874/com.example.utkarsh.places W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.utkarsh.places-1/lib/arm
06-26 16:17:11.057 8874-8874/com.example.utkarsh.places W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
06-26 16:17:11.122 8874-8874/com.example.utkarsh.places D/resuktfvvvfdfd: onCreate: 
06-26 16:17:11.174 8874-8874/com.example.utkarsh.places D/connected: false
06-26 16:17:11.226 8874-8924/com.example.utkarsh.places D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
06-26 16:17:11.280 8874-8924/com.example.utkarsh.places I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 166ada0, Ifd751822f5
                                                                  Build Date                       : 01/26/16
                                                                  OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.06.00.05
                                                                  Local Branch                     : AU12_SBA
                                                                  Remote Branch                    : 
                                                                  Remote Branch                    : 
                                                                  Reconstruct Branch               : 
06-26 16:17:11.288 8874-8924/com.example.utkarsh.places I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
06-26 16:17:15.295 8874-8874/com.example.utkarsh.places D/connected1: true
06-26 16:17:15.296 8874-8874/com.example.utkarsh.places D/mvkvkmvkmvkm: callPlaceDetectionApi: 
06-26 16:17:15.328 8874-8874/com.example.utkarsh.places D/result: com.google.android.gms.location.places.internal.zzi$1@753c4cb
```

Comment: check Log Level in Android Studio.Is it `Info`? B'coz in `Logcat` all are `Debug` mode and in `onResult` it's `Info` mode

Comment: i have checked it, no info mode  appears in logcat, this is in verbose

Comment: is it `onResult` execute? did you tried with debuging?

Comment: i checked it nothing appears , is my location not getting identified ?

Comment: hey, this is the complete log with package name as filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On printing status in on result method of likely places it came "ERROR OPERATION FAILED " further the main error was that the meta data was not under application tag now it is running correctly